# Blog page not working? Or we can't access old blogs anymore?

Tags: bug, blog

So I was browsing the old blog posts when I came to this one:

[Playing with Partitions: Euler’s Pentagonal Theorem](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/25/playing-with-partitions-eulers-pentagonal-theorem/)

I then tried to click the link to see the previous blog:

[image]

However, it brought me to this page:

[404 - File or directory not found.](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%ef%ac%81elds/)

which is quite saddening.  I tried [asking around in the Blog Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/conversation/blogs-being-weird), but Martin Sleziak and mixedmath ♦ were unable to figure out was going on here.

Is this a bug?  I doubt we aren't allowed to view older blogs anymore.

---

(and if this is a bug, hopefully we can get this fixed)

Comment: The blog was discontinued. A network-wide decision. You can find the archived versions of blog posts. For example, by starting from [here](http://math.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for that!

Comment: I see, need to get to bottom of that page and click on older entries to get mine from August 2014

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Exactly from the link you provided I get to this: http://math.blogoverflow.com/tag/binary-quadratic-forms/ or to this http://math.blogoverflow.com/page/2/ From either of those links, when I get to WIll Jagy's post and click on "more" or on the title of the post, I get the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak That is a bit strange. For example [here](http://math.blogoverflow.com/category/advanced-high-school/) I can click on "more", and I get to see the entire blog post. Hmm. When I click that now, I get to see the entire posts right away. Something about this is not intuitive.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I went through all posts. I might have missed something, but Will Jagy's post is the only one which behaves in this way. (At least on my computer.)